# Can accounts be merged?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

I have posted on tex.stackexchange as an unregistered user for some time. But it seems that this lead to two accounts with my name. Now on one of my PC the site no longer recognized me, so I created a real account with an openid. And now I have three identities: (user 955, 958 and 2388). Can this accounts be merged?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste

Answer (score 5):

I have moved your accounts – your [new account](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) is the one that had an OpenID associated.

However, all badges were lost during the merging. I suspect that this is normal and that they will be re-attached in a few hours. If that doesn’t happen, please follow up and we’ll ask Jeff.

Comment: He's already getting some badges back :)

Comment: Thanks. And don't worry about badges. I'm more interested in the list of my answers and comments. - And I'm a "she".

Comment: Luckily we didn't do it at the same time :-) I was just making screenshots of the three account pages (kind of quick info backup if something strange happened) when I noticed the merge has been done.

Comment: @Stefan: I’m hoping that the software has precautions for this kind of conditions in place. But true, this is kind of a race. Next time I’ll *first* delete the flag, *then* perform the action so as to mark it complete for the other moderators.

Comment: @Konrad: That's good! Marking as already completed prevents double actions.

Comment: @Konrad When it comes to mod tools, hoping there are safeguards in place is usually the road to pain :)

Comment: @Ulrike: sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Flag one of your posts for moderator attention and explain your situation there.

Comment: For this time, I've done it for you ;)